How to automatically have full access to PR comments in Bitbucket
One of my colleagues is admin on a Bitbucket repository, but he can’t see my PR comments. Does he need to grant access to himself for each branch/repository separately? Or is there a way to automatically get full access to comments in all situations. As an admin, one should not have such a problem. But he has.
As this colleague is an admin himself, I want him to be able to fix it. So what should he do?
Or is there something I need to do?
Note that:

My colleague can read all the repositories
My colleague can see his own comments
My colleague can contribute to all repositories.
On previous PRs, he can read the comments.

I find it very strange that someone has the right to fully contribute to a repository but can't read my PR comments.
Keep in mind that this is about giving access to reading comments specifically. Access to other things have already been given and works fine.

Can you confirm if your comments are marked with PENDING? And any screenshots/screen recordings to help reconstruct this in a non-production system would be helpful. Thanks!

There are no branch-specific permissions required, right?
